# Can't create a team within Organization in Liferay 6.1 CE

Tags: liferay-6

It seams that we are not able to create a team within Organization but within sites.

Any suggestion ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Liferay 6.1 has undergone a lot of changes. Check out this [link](http://www.liferay.com/web/jorge.ferrer/blog/-/blogs/7858337)

To just give you highlight.

1. Communities have been renamed to sites
2. Only Sites can have pages
3. You have to associate Site with an organization to have organization pages
4. Organization is just a way to group of users(Heirarchical grouping) by default. Only if it is required to have pages, one can associate site with that
5. Now based on above change, it only makes sense to have teams within organization.